# Line underneath my menu bar!

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, menubar

When you create a menu bar, a funny line appears underneath (for XP and Win7 at least). How can I get rid of this line? I know that some applications, such as Firefox and Thunderbird, have done so.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

I am programming in C, using the Windows API. My menu is loaded from a resource file.

Comment: The Mozilla products are not using the native menu (Or scrollbars or anything else for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that line is supposed to be there (Run a simple application like calc and see) If you look at an application like Explorer (Or IE4-6) in XP, its menu is actually a toolbar inside of a rebar.

If you look at a function like GetMenuBarInfo() you will see there is no border property you can query or set.

If a 1 pixel line is that important, you probably have to A) Do some owner drawing on the menu to paint over that line or B) Implement a custom menu control (MS even has a [tutorial for IE/Explorer style menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775450(VS.85).aspx))

Comment: Ah, this explains a lot. Cheers!